# Асинхронное выполнение функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность, асинхронность

Функция, которая принимает параметры:

```
void log(string q, bool w) {
    mutex.lock();
    cout <<
    ...
}
```

Эта функция постоянно вызывается из разных потоков. Как выполнить вызов асинхронно?
Пытался сделать через

```
std::async(&log, q, true);
```

но как-то не заладилось..

Comment: А что ты хочешь от асинхронности? У тебя же mutex-ом лочится выполнения. Т.е. в один момент времени только один поток с ней работает. И `std::async` не всегда создаёт новый поток, согласно спецификации `The template function async runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.`

Comment: а какова цель? есть подозрение, что таковой асинхронный вызов будет обходиться дороже, чем ожидание на мьютексе...

Comment: Изначально мне нужно, что бы писались логи в консоль отдельно от потоков с обработкой, что бы они не ждали, когда им разрешат вывести лог, а сразу продолжали работу дальше. У меня была идея создать вектор, в который буду пулить логи, и создать отдельный поток, который постоянно будет проверять этот вектор на наличие новых логов, но мне кажется, что эта идея себя не оправдает

Answer (score 1):

Пока вы не сохраните значение в фьючерсе, `async` не будет выполняться параллельно.

Простейший пример:

```
void sss(int x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i, Sleep(1))
        cout << x;
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    /* auto g = */ async(sss,1);
    auto f = async(sss,2);
    f.get();
}
```

Если вы оставите все, как есть - сначала будут выведены единички, только потом - двойки. А если раскомментарите - пойдут параллельно.

Дело в том, что фактически вы при вызове `async` без присваивания убиваете возвращаемый фьючерс, что приводит к ожиданию завершения параллельного потока.

Если вас не очень интересует результат - это тот случай, когда лучше подойдет `thread` + `detach`.

Comment: Всё же `async()` практически не дал прироста скорости. А что вы подразумеваете под `thread` + `detach`? Функция может вызываться больше 10 раз в секунду, и создавать каждый раз новый поток не кажется мне хорошей идеей.

Comment: Это второй вопрос - даст это прирост или не даст :) Вы спросили о том, как работать с `async`, а не как выводить в лог, правда? На ваш вопрос я ответил... А так - да, для такой мелкой функции все сожрут накладные расходы. Я бы накапливал данные для вывода в лог где-то в памяти, как, скажем, вектор строк, а по достижении определенного размера разово сбрасывал на диск...

Comment: @Harry а потом при некотором сбое программы в логе ничего не будет важного, т.к. данные остались в векторе и не успели сохраниться

Comment: Тогда не морочьте голову, работайте синхронно и со сбросом на диск при каждой записи. Можете создать один поток и передавать всю информацию ему, а уж он будет работать с диском, а не вызывать `async` десять раз в секунду...

Comment: @Harry Интересное предложение, т.к. мне нужны логи только в консоли, то можно проверять активность окна консоли, и выводить логи в неё, в ином случае скидывать их в вектор, который будет выведен при переключении на консоль. Что бы не плодить темы, спрошу сразу - можно проверять активность окна в консольном приложении так, что бы не нагружать проц?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void f(int i)
{
 //Sleep(10);
 std::cout<<"i="<<i;
}
int     WINAPI  WinMain                    (HINSTANCE  Instance   ,
                                            HINSTANCE  Previous   ,
                                            PSTR       CommandLine,
                                            int        Show       )
{
 int Result=0;
 std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
 auto g=std::async(f, 3);
 auto t=std::async(f, 4);
 std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
 if (RegisterWindowClass(Instance))
 {
  if (CreateMainWindow(MainWindow, Instance, Show))
  {
   Result=MainLoop();
  }
 }
 return Result;
}
```

Функция вообще не выполнилась.